# OpenCV library importing error with android

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am using eclipse Luna with android sdk 23 , OpnCV version is 2.4.8 . When I am importing library , library show me following errors

```
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    OpenCV Library - 2.4.8      Unknown Java Problem

make: *** No rule to make target `jni/OpenCVLibrary-2.4.8.cpp', needed by `obj/local/armeabi/objs/OpenCVLibrary-2.4.8/OpenCVLibrary-2.4.8.o'. Stop.
```

I visit some resources for it like [this](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2983) but didn't understand.
I am following the complete instructions from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_dev_intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading and installing OpenCV library from google play.I installed OpenCV manager.It worked fine for me. 
I ran few samples of OpenCV, programmed in Java.

Comment: It is used when we test our application , First I have to remove error's then I can test my application on mobile. Isn't it ? or we can use opencv manager in eclipse ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Native Code, you will also need [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html). You will need to provide path to `<NDK-ROOT>/ndk-build` in order to built the native code. Check out [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_dev_intro.html) official tutorial for building native part of the application.